# What is the best age to start running distances longer than 15k / halfmarathon?

Tags: running

I have a friend that is 16 and wants to do a half marathon this year. From what i know its not recommended to run great distances as a half marathon under the age of 18.

Are there any scientifical studies about age and long distance running?

Comment: This seems like a decision that should be made with consultation of a doctor and trainer not a bunch of clods on the Internet.

Comment: @waxeagle Until I changed by GP, I was told that all running at HM or longer was definitely "_very bad_" for your body. My new GP runs 3-4 Marathons per and obviously have a very different opinion :-) I'm not sure sure this type of question will get a better _objective_ answer at the average GP than here :-)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

According to [an article](http://www.livestrong.com/article/515033-running-guidelines-for-kids/) in LiveStrong:

> **Distance**
>
> According to Running Times, the maximum recommended distance
> for young runners varies by age. Kids younger than age 5 can
> participate in designated kiddie events but should focus primarily on
> running as part of natural play. By age 5, kids are ready for light
> training leading up to a mile-long run. Preteens and early teens can
> manage 5K runs, and some early teens are ready for a 10K. Older teens
> are generally ready to compete on an adult level.

and

> **Cautions**
>
> Rapidly growing bones and muscles are increased risks for injuries
> such as shin splints. Undiagnosed medical conditions such as asthma or
> heart defects can affect a child's ability to participate in
> high-impact sports. **Schedule your child for a full sports physical
> before beginning serious training. Follow the doctor's recommendations
> for training schedules, rest breaks and cross training in other
> sports.** Have any injuries or persistent pain thoroughly checked. Make
> sure your child drinks plenty of water or sports drinks, warms up
> thoroughly before each workout, and cools down appropriately at the
> end of each session.

[Runner's World](http://www.runnersworld.com/article/0,7120,s6-238-267--13034-F,00.html) also discussed running and age:

> Framing marathon performance as an age issue is wrong, says Terrence
> Mahon, coach to Olympic marathoners Deena Kastor, Ryan Hall, and
> Mahon's wife, Jen Rhines. What's key, says Mahon, isn't chronological
> age but athletic age—a runner's history of aerobic training—and that
> goes for elites and nonelites alike.
>
> In the past, coaches worried that turning to the marathon too soon
> would unduly shorten a runner's career. [Coach Brad] Hudson ran his first marathon
> at age 12. "I think it hurt my career to go to the marathon so young,"
> says Hudson, who set his PR (2:13) at 23. Today, he doesn't advise
> kids to begin racing marathons as young as he did, but he says that
> **high school and collegiate runners can handle high volumes of training
> if they increase their mileage gradually and take steps to avoid
> burnout.**
>
> What successful young marathoners like Wanjiru have in common with
> older ones like Tomescu–Dita is a solid mileage base. "**There are
> athletes out there running marathons at 21, but if you look at most of
> them, you'll see they've had a high training volume for a good many
> years before they've run the event**," Mahon says. "Ryan Hall and Dathan
> Ritzenhein were running 90 miles per week in high school, so for them
> to make the transition to 100—mile weeks wasn't so hard."
>
> Obviously, young runners outside the elite ranks don't need to attain
> that kind of mileage. **But the same principle applies—to prepare for
> the marathon, first build a strong endurance base, then adopt a
> graduated training program that builds to the marathon distance**, says
> Jack Daniels, an exercise physiologist and head distance coach at the
> Center for High Altitude Training at Northern Arizona University in
> Flagstaff.

In the end, age is probably not the biggest factor - it's the amount of distance training that the athlete's body is conditioned for.

Comment: While I generally agree with the quotes about, I think you should note that there are are _very_ big difference in the burden between an HM and a M!

Comment: @TonnyMadsen - I agree. The first quote mentioned that early teens might be ready for a 10k, I thought that it would be best to mention that a young runner would need to build up to the HM over time.

Answer (score 2):

**Are there any scientifical studies about age and long distance running?**

See [here](https://sports.stackexchange.com/a/1364).

In short, ages of winners in strength and speed events have historically peaked earlier than endurance events. The mean age of Olympic gold medal male winners from 1896-1980 in long distance events are relatively higher than shorter distance events.